# How to merge lead_source in a report?

Tags: reporting

I need to create a report, where 4 of the 7 lead_sources in use, should be grouped together.

How can I perform that?

Comment: You can use bucketing for this.

Comment: yea, I did use it, but missed the part where you can add a filter on the new bucket field, which I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Bucketing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFYEtBtLHG4), which allows you to group Picklist values for reporting.

https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_bucketing_picklist.htm